# Iterate over two arrays with bash

Tags: arrays, bash

Let's say I have two arrays *of the same length* :

```
array1=('a' 'b' 'c')
array2=('1' '2' '3')
```

I would like to iterate over these two arrays in order to apply a command. My current (not sexy) solution is the following :

```
for iter in `seq 0 $((${#array1[@]}-1))`
do  
    echo "First parameter : ${array1[$iter]} -- second parameter : ${array2[$iter]}"
done
```

Is there anything better ?

Comment: I think your current solution is fine.

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid `seq` in `bash`:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#array1[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "First parameter : ${array1[$i]} -- second parameter : ${array2[$i]}"
done
First parameter : a -- second parameter : 1
First parameter : b -- second parameter : 2
First parameter : c -- second parameter : 3
```